# UITabBar image load issue when Touch ID verification

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios8, xcode6, uistoryboardsegue, touch-id

I've been working all over this issue for days but no luck. Here it is:

I have a `UIViewController` to `UITabBarController` set up. User enters a password to access the tab-based views etc. This is all good. However, I recently added `Touch ID` support to my app but when I have a successful verification with it, It **loads tab images after couple of minutes** **yeah seriously couple of minutes!**; except the tab that is active.

This is a storyboard application and I'm presenting tab controller with a segue.

When I press the button to perform segue, its all ok:
[image]

But when I perform the segue after Touch ID verification with `performSegueWithIdentifier:`
[image]

I tried lazy loading, using IB and everything but can't find a solution.

Is there anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what was wrong if anyone still wonders. Since touch id is executed in `evaluatePolicy` block, so to break out of execution and having a code block run simultaneously, all you need to do is create a function and call `dispatch_async` with `dispatch_get_main_queue` then do whatever you want to do in there.